Maintaining number formatting when exporting to excel
I have this dataframe
df <- data.frame(status=c('single', 'married', 'married', "fff"),
                 education=c(3456, 898989899, 23939004, NA),
                 income=c('34,5%', '88.456%', '92', NA))
 

I did some modifications in the formating of the above numbers using
my_numbers <- function(x) structure(x, class = c('my_numbers', 'numeric'))  
format.my_numbers <- function(x,...)NextMethod(sci = FALSE, big.mark='.')
print.my_numbers <- function(x,...) print(format(x), quote = FALSE)    
'[.my_numbers' <- function(x,...,drop = FALSE)  my_numbers(NextMethod('['))
 
x <- my_numbers(df)

df <- lapply(df, my_numbers)
df2<- bind_rows(df)



 df2
    A tibble: 4 × 3
      status     education   income    
      <my_nmbrs> <my_nmbrs>  <my_nmbrs>
    1 single           3.456 34,5%     
    2 married    898.989.899 88.456%   
    3 married     23.939.004 92   
     4 fff                 NA NA   

I want to maintain this formating when extracting df2 to excel. I tried
library(xlsx) 

----
wb <- createWorkbook() 
CellStyle(wb) 
sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet1") 
  
addDataFrame(df2, sheet)
saveWorkbook(wb = wb, file = "New_df.xlsx")

but with no success. Any ideas?
An alternative approach would be the following
library(xlsx)
df1<-df %>%   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~formatC(., format="d", big.mark=".")))
df1[df1=='NA']<-NA

 
wb <- createWorkbook() 
CellStyle(wb) 
sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet1") 
addDataFrame(df1, sheet)
saveWorkbook(wb = wb, file = "New_df.xlsx")

which seems to be working and it is very fast given the millions of cells that I have. Does this make sense?
I have 300000 rows and 900 columns

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79186240/putting-dots-to-every-three-digits-of-numerical-values-in-a-dataframe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79186929/maintaning-formating-when-exporting-to-excel Why? You do not need mynumbers, and as explained in comments to previous question: why are you trying to operate on character columns containing words?

This seems like a duplicate of your prior two questions on this topic. As I commented in both of those questions, don't try to convert your R data to a formatted character format if you want to export it into Excel as a number. That won't work. When you change numbers to be a custom format in R, they become character data, and the R->Excel link has no way to know it's really numbers. Rather, use openxlsx::createStyle() to specify the number format to apply to the Excel cells. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800433/openxlsx-format-cells-as-number-with-comma-and-decimal-places

Thanks @Jon Spring. It takes a lot of time to do this conversion if I use createStyle, as I have millions of cells. The above code that I display in this question is very very fast but I am not sure how to maintain this format when extracting df2 to excel. In that regard, I believe that it is a different question.

This is an XY problem. Now you understand why your question is incorrect. You do not need to do anything in R. your goal is to ensure you have . as the thousand separator in EXCEL and not in R. All your code is incorrect. The number formatting done in R is just for displaying the results on your screen. Not to be written to drive.

So @Onyambu, you suggest using createStyle?

What I am trying to say is that if I do not do any conversion within R and use createStyle to make the conversion within excel, this process will take me many many hours. That's why I used the above code

You have not yet clearly identified your actual goals in a way that will help us find the best approach for your situation. "I have X tables with approximately Y rows and Z columns each. I would like to output these to Excel so that the figures remain as numbers in Excel, but with [two] custom formats, specified below. I have tried A, but this resulted in text in Excel, not numbers. I tried B, but this was too slow, taking [C amount of time] for a test table." If you skip any mention of B, we will think you are not listening when you keep re-describing A.

In general, you can either convert to formatted characters (no longer numeric) and output as is to Excel, or send to Excel as numbers and subsequently specify the custom formatting. If the question relates to speed, your question should show a sample that is at least moderately taxing, and then we can benchmark if there are approaches that work acceptably.

@JonSpring, thank you. I provided an alternative code in my question which is very fast (less that 15 minutes) compared to createStyle that takes 9 hours. I will try also the suggested answer of Onyamby to see if the speed is good

You have been asking the same question several times. Here is a solution that should work for your xlsx. Note that only the numeric columns are impacted
library(openxlsx)
df <- data.frame(status=c('single', 'married', 'married', "fff"),
                 education=c(3456, 898989899, 23939004, NA),
                 income=c('34,5%', '88.456%', '92', NA),
                 another_col = sample(200000, 4))
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(income = parse_number(income) /100^grepl("%", income))

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
writeData(wb, "Sheet1", df1)

addStyle(wb, "Sheet1", style = createStyle(numFmt = "#,##0.00"), 
         rows = seq(nrow(df)) + 1, 
         cols = which(sapply(df, is.numeric)), gridExpand = TRUE)



addStyle(wb, "Sheet1", style = createStyle(numFmt = "0.00%"), 
         rows = seq(nrow(df)) + 1, 
         cols = grep("%", df), gridExpand = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "numeric_formatted_numbers.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)


Note that columns B and D are numeric while column C is in percentage format which is still numeric

Thank you @Onyambu. I will check the speed and get back to you asap.

If I want to impact also the character columns with the percetanges so as to be displayed as numbers as well within excel, how your code would be modified? It is crucial for me to learn that aspect as well. Many thanks!

@newfinder you cannot have characters mixed with numbers. Unless you clean your data first. Check the edit

Thank you @Onyambu. I will accept the answer. Before doing that two small questions. If I have many character columns should I need to repeat the  parse_number() command for every such column?  I have in total 900 columns. The other thing  is that the code is  still slow. Is there a faster way? Many thanks again!

@newfinder you will have to use parse_number for all the columns that you want as numeric. There is no workaround that. The slow code is when writing the data to xlsx. Note that if you have 900 columns, once you have the data as numeric, there is no advantage of having the formating. ie its 900 columns, No one is going to go through the xlsx file column by column to take a look at it. So it does not make sense to use . for thousand separator or even to have %. Its 900 columns. Anytime its read into R/python etc, the values will be read as numeric, discarding all formats. So why use format?

If I have a single number say 8, instead of 3456 in the above df, the code produces 008. Is there a workaround for that case?

@newfinder the code should only produce 8.00 cant tell why its not doing that. Anyway, still have a question for you. WHY do you need to format the data this way in excel? Seems this is still an xyproblem. The same way you were trying to solve using the printed results inR yet was incorrect approach, might be the exactly what you are facing. Once youve formatted the excel, what next?? Ask yourself that. Why cant the excel just have numbers without the format??

OK, will do that. Makes sense. Thanks a lot!
